# HikariCP ignores connection timeout, and not reads from slave DB

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hikaricp

I have configured DB connection using hibernate with hibernate-hikaricp 4.3.10. 
 
I have simple test that read some values from db. I'm expecting, that when i cut off connection to master server, hikari will detect it and send query to slave server, but it just hangs undefined long. No attempts to ask slave db nor mySQLExceptions, from what I can conclude that hikari/mysql-driver ignores my settings of timeout and master-slave replication. 
Could you say, what is going wrong?

my hibernate cfg.file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url">jdbc:mysql:replication://master:3306, slave:3306/models?loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=5000&amp;loadBalanceConnectionGroup=cgroup&amp;loadBalanceEnableJMX=true&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;autoReconnectForPools=true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize">250</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.connectionTestQuery">show tables</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout">10000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.autoCommit">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.readOnly">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout">10000</property>



        <!-- List of class mapping  -->
        <mapping class="my.pack.csamodels.entities.MyModel"/>


    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and my simple test

```
    @Test
public void testDbAcess() {
    SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("accounts_hib.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    session.setDefaultReadOnly(true);
    try {
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT id FROM accounts LIMIT 5");
        List results = query.list();
        assertTrue(!results.isEmpty());
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

### UPD

I can see in logs hikari daemon while my query hangs

```
  21:44:23.648 [Hikari Housekeeping Timer (pool HikariPool-0)] DEBUG HikariPool - Before cleanup pool stats HikariPool-0 (total=0, inUse=0, avail=0, waiting=0)
  21:44:23.648 [Hikari Housekeeping Timer (pool HikariPool-0)] DEBUG HikariPool - After cleanup pool stats HikariPool-0 (total=0, inUse=0, avail=0, waiting=0)
  21:44:53.648 [Hikari Housekeeping Timer (pool HikariPool-0)] DEBUG HikariPool - Before cleanup pool stats HikariPool-0 (total=0, inUse=0, avail=0, waiting=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't be using the `MysqlDataSource` in this case.  You'll want to locate the configure the driver through the URL, which basically means change `hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url` to `hibernate.hikari.jdbcUrl`.  You'll also likely need to specify the replication driver class directly, `hibernate.hikari.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver`.

Second, `show tables` is a horrible test query (expensive).  You shouldn't need a test query with MySQL anyway, as it supports the JDBC4 `isValid()` API.

Lastly, is `readOnly` really want you want?  This application only runs queries, never inserts/update/deletes data?  If so, its fine, otherwise that looks odd.

EDIT: Stop using `autoReconnect` and `autoReconnectForPools`, they are likely impeding failover. Additionally, you will need `allowMasterDownConnections` set to `true` if you are downing the master DB. See [this MySQL bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50105).

Comment: i have changed my dataSource properties to hikari.jdbcUrl and driverClass name, just as you said, but still no result. my query just hangs when i jamming db connection, in jamming program i can see, that my test tries to retrieve connection with db every few seconds.